# How do I change a variable per onChange event?

Tags: javascript, onchange

I want the # of days to show up based on Month selected in a drop down list.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    }
</script>

<select id="mySelect" name="month" onChange="myFunction()">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

$daysInMonth = ? <----- This is what I need to change per onChange

<?php
    $start = 0;
    while($start = $daysInMonth) {
        $start = $start + 1;
        echo '<option value="'.$start.'">'.$start.'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Much help is appreciated. Thank You in advance!
For those who are curious, I plan on adding one to $daysInMonth if $year % 4 == 0 and February is selected... (leap year)

My confusion comes from...
Normally, on an onChange event, I would add

But how does it work with adding or changing php?

Comment: is this how php works? Isn't php rendered once and then no more computation happens?

Comment: The php has already rendered. Use js to update the page without cause a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

@Donald Faulknor

Php is used for server side rendering. When PHP is finished with rendering and the site has been transmitted to the browser of the client then the browser executes the javascript tag. So javascript does not now that the page has been rendered by php or java.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do like this.. 
         /In onchange funtion do something like this../

```
        <script>
        function myFunction(month,year)
        {

            monthdays=getDaysInMonth(month,year);
            var days='';

                        start=0;
                        while(monthdays!=0){
                        days+= "<option value="+start+">"+start+"</option>";
                        monthdays--;
                        }
                        jQuery("#daysSelect").html(days);



        }

    </script>

 <?php $year=date('Y'); ?>


<select id="mySelect" name="month" onChange="myFunction(this.value,'<?php 
 echo $year; ?>')">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```